# Google Sign: GoogleAPIClient not connecting

Tags: android, google-signin

I integrated google sign in in my app, that works well on L and M devices. But for some reason not on KitKat and below. I debugged it and it always calls `onConnectionFailed`, but why? Below is the LoginActivity:

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        btn_google = (CircleButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_login_google);
        btn_google.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
                    mShouldResolve = true;
                    resolveSignInError();
                }
            }
        });

        //Build GoogleApiClient
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(Plus.API)
                .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.PROFILE))
                .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.EMAIL))
                .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN))
                .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.PLUS_ME))
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();

    }



    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
                mShouldResolve = false;
            }

            mIntentInProgress = false;

            if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
        } 
    }


    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        //connect GoogleApiClient
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        //disconnect GoogleApiClient
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    /*
    Used for resolving errors during signIn
    */
    private void resolveSignInError() {
        if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
            try {
                mIntentInProgress = true;
                connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, RC_SIGN_IN);

            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                mIntentInProgress = false;
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();

            }
        }
    }

    /*
    When the GoogleApiClient object is unable to establish a connection onConnectionFailed() is called
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        if (!result.hasResolution()) {
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(result.getErrorCode(), this,
                    0).show();
            return;
        }

        if (!mIntentInProgress) {

            connectionResult = result;


            if (mShouldResolve) {

                resolveSignInError();

            }
        }

    }

    /*
    on the successfull connection onConnected is called
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
        mShouldResolve = false;

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            checkLocationPermission();
        }else{
            get_user_details();

        }

    }

    private void get_user_details(){

        try {
            if (Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient) != null) {
                Person person = Plus.PeopleApi
                        .getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);

                personName_google = person.getDisplayName();
                email_google = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);

            } else {

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int arg0) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

        public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 100;

    public boolean checkLocationPermission() {

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            // Asking user if explanation is needed
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                    Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS)) {

                // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
                // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
                // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

                //Prompt the user once explanation has been shown
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);


            } else {
                // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
            }
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    // permission was granted. Do the
                    // contacts-related task you need to do.
                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                            Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS)
                            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                        get_user_details();
                    }

                } else {

                    // Permission denied, Disable the functionality that depends on this permission.
                    Toast.makeText(this, "permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    dialog_general_prog.dismiss();
                }
                return;
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: you have to generate signed apk and then after check it will work fine...

Comment: hm but why should it not work on debug mode. never had this case...I know I need to generate a release api key after I want to upload on store but I do not get it why login not works